# Symfony2: Pass Parameter to Form entity object for query_builder

Tags: forms, symfony

In My form i use this code

```
$form->add('user', 'entity', 
        array(
                'label' => 'User Name',
                'class' => 'DotArtBundle:User',
                'property' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->where('u.type = 1');
                            }
            )
    );
```

I want

if user role is `ROLE_ADMIN` run this code and show all user (This code do this)

if user role is `ROLE_USER` this code only show authenticated user in list

```
  'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
         return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->where('u.type = 1 and u.id = ' . $this->getUser()->getId());
    }
```

**Error**
I check this code and return error:

```
 $where  = 'u.id = '.$userid;
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder($poduct)
              ->add('user', 'entity', 
                      array(
                        'label' => 'نانم کاربری',
                        'class' => 'DotArtBundle:User',
                        'property' => 'name',
                        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                                               return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->where($where);
                                                }
                                )
                        )
Notice: Undefined variable: where in C:\xampp\htdocs\ArtGirl\src\Dot\ArtBundle\Controller\ProductController.php line 38
```

Comment: Have you considered using the [Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-user-data)?

Comment: no, I define `$form = $this->createForm....()->add(...)->getForm();`

Comment: Your question is about asking how to access the role of the user then?

Comment: If user role is `ADMIN` show in ComboBox all user,
else if user role is `USER` show in ComboBox just Authenticated User

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
$where  = '';
$userid = $this->getUser()->getId();
if (!$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')){
    $where = ' and u.id = ' . $userid;
}


$form->add('user', 'entity', 
    array(
            'label' => 'نانم کاربری',
            'class' => 'DotArtBundle:User',
            'property' => 'name',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($where){
                            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->where('u.type = 1 '.$where);
                        }
        )
)
```